# How to parse this JSON file

Tags: python, json

I am trying to parse a JSON file using a Python script:

```
import json from pprint import pprint

with open("apc.json") as json_file:  
  json_data = json.load(json_file) 
  print (json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))

for item in json_data:    
    y_tube = item.get('bin')
    print(y_tube)
    for each_dict in y_tube:
        print each_dict.get("item")
```

For this JSON file:

```
{  
   "bin_contents":  

   {
    "bin_A":
    [
      "oreo_mega_stuf","champion_copper_plus_spark_plug","expo_dry_erase_board_eraser","kong_duck_dog_toy"
    ],
    "bin_B":
    [
      "genuine_joe_plastic_stir_sticks"
    ],
    "bin_C":
    [
      "munchkin_white_hot_duck_bath_toy"
    ],
    "bin_D":
    [
      "crayola_64_ct"
    ],
    "bin_E":
    [
      "mommys_helper_outlet_plugs","sharpie_accent_tank_style_highlighters","kong_air_dog_squeakair_tennis_ball"
    ],
    "bin_F":
    [
      "stanley_66_052"
    ],
    "bin_G":
    [
      "safety_works_safety_glasses","dr_browns_bottle_brush","laugh_out_loud_joke_book"
    ],
    "bin_H":
    [
      "cheezit_big_original","paper_mate_12_count_mirado_black_warrior"
    ],
    "bin_I":
    [
      "feline_greenies_dental_treats","elmers_washable_no_run_school_glue"
    ],
    "bin_J":
    [
      "mead_index_cards","rolodex_jumbo_pencil_cup","mead_index_cards","first_years_take_and_toss_straw_cup"
    ],
    "bin_K":
    [
      "highland_6539_self_stick_notes","mark_twain_huckleberry_finn"
    ],
    "bin_L":
    [
      "kyjen_squeakin_eggs_plush_puppies","kong_sitting_frog_dog_toy"
    ]   },

  "work_order":   [
    {
      "bin": "bin_A",
      "item": "oreo_mega_stuf"
    },
    {
      "bin": "bin_B",
      "item": "genuine_joe_plastic_stir_sticks"
    },
    {
      "bin": "bin_C",
      "item": "munchkin_white_hot_duck_bath_toy"
    },
    {
      "bin": "bin_D",
      "item": "crayola_64_ct"
    },
    {
      "bin": "bin_E",
      "item": "mommys_helper_outlet_plugs"
    },
    {
      "bin": "bin_F",
      "item": "stanley_66_052"
    },
    {
      "bin": "bin_G",
      "item": "safety_works_safety_glasses"
    },
    {
      "bin": "bin_H",
      "item": "cheezit_big_original"
    },
    {
      "bin": "bin_I",
      "item": "feline_greenies_dental_treats"
    },
    {
      "bin": "bin_J",
      "item": "mead_index_cards"
    },
    {
      "bin": "bin_K",
      "item": "highland_6539_self_stick_notes"
    },
    {
      "bin": "bin_L",
      "item": "kyjen_squeakin_eggs_plush_puppies"
    } 


 ] 
}
```

Expected output:

> Parser should count number of items from `bin_contents` and parse the `bin` name and `item` from `work_order`.

Example:

```
Number of items in Bin-A is 4      #obtained form bin_contents  
  bin_A - oreo_mega_stuf             #obtainedfrom work_order
```

I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Could you correct your code pasting? Your first couple of lines appear to be missing newlines. It'd also help if you described a sample of what output you're expecting.

Comment: Thank you for the edit! done!

Answer (score 0):

json_data is a dict, so the way your loop is written, item is a key, and thus a string, which gets you your error.  I don't see any bin item, so it isn't clear how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating the wrong thing.

```
for item in json_data:
```

Iterates the keys (strings) of the `dict`, not the values, so on the first loop, you're probably getting the `unicode` object `u"bin_contents"`. not the `dict` associated with it. Perhaps you wanted:

```
for item in json_data.viewvalues():
```

Note: It still won't `get` anything useful, because your example has no key named `bin`, but that's a separate issue.